# Is there a single word for "not allowed to be released?"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a single word for something that is there but not yet released because it has not been allowed to be released? I am an artist interested in words having to do with the blocking, stifling  of a person due to oppression, violence and or fear. The oppression, violence and fear can also be internal due to learned behavior in an environment filled with these things.

Comment: "Embargoed" can work, but the oppression and fear have to be explained separately.

Comment: Already proposed *censored* or *prohibited* may fit, as well as *"banned"* or  *"outlaw"*.

Comment: “Intimidation”, “coercion”, and possibly “extortion” might apply to the oppression, violence and fear.

Answer (score 5):

A word often used in this context is *[suppressed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suppress)*:

> foreign correspondent's copy is not censored, but certain news is  *suppressed*
>
> the incipient uprising had been completely  *suppressed*

This can also be applied to internal thoughts or processes:

> disciplined to *suppress* his personal impulses.
>
> it has been hard to *suppress* the question.
>
> the satisfaction of a *suppressed* creative wish [T.S. Eliot]

Answer (score 2):

***[Censored](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/censored)*** is the term that comes to mind reading your question:

> - suppressed or subject to censorship. *The censored press in some countries.

The Free Dictionary

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship):

> **Censorship** is the suppression of free speech, public communication or other information which may be considered objectionable, harmful,
>   sensitive, politically incorrect or inconvenient as determined by
>   governments, media outlets, authorities or other groups or
>   institutions.

Comment: Good answer. If you don't like my edit, delete it.

Answer (score 1):

What about a scenario where the dictator of Ruritania has **embargoed** the sale of books written by the country's most respected writer and defender of civil liberties.

**Embargo:** Stoppage, impediment; an official ban on any activity (Oxford Living Dictionary)

In the alternative, what about the dictator of a country who has **interdicted** the books of the country's most famous writer and defender of civil liberties.

**Interdict:** To prohibit (an action or thing) or forbid (someone) to do something. (The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

I think the word [***classified***](http://kept%20secret%20from%20all%20but%20a%20few%20people%20in%20the%20government) would be fitting.

Merriam Webster's definition: Kept secret from all but a few people in the government.

Answer (score 0):

**Unmanifested**

> Not manifested or made evident; invisible, hidden.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/unmanifested

**non-manifestation**

> manifestation - 3. outward or perceptible indication; materialization:

manifestation. (n.d.). Dictionary.com Unabridged. Retrieved October 1, 2016 from Dictionary.com website http://www.dictionary.com/browse/manifestation

Answer (score 0):

Confined, restricted, barred, detained, retained, seized, captured, and trapped of course. I also like a previous answer's word "suppressed".

Confined: unable to leave a place (whether because of sickness, imprisonment, etc.)

Restricted: limited, kept from doing something or going somewhere

Barred: prevented from something (usually escape, but also often used for preventing pretty much anything such as an achievement or job)

Detained: kept back or withheld. It's used in terms of someone being trapped somewhere or held back, either permanently or temporarily. It's often used for getting arrested, but can be used in many other circumstances.

Retained: held on to (physically or mentally). This word is a little bit more abstract in context to your definition. Unlike detained, it's hardly ever used in terms of someone themselves being retained. Instead, people often retain (hold onto, keep, maintain) certain habits, characteristics, feelings, items, properties, memories, etc. It fits perfectly (in context of your purposed) for retaining fear or certain behaviors and memories in the past. These things often in itself hold you back from being released as well.

Seized: Grabbed, grasped, forcibly taken

Captured: to be taken prisoner, forcibly taken

Trapped: to be caught in something or by something (for any number of time, whether briefly of long)